# SQL query not working properly (not sure about it)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: **ORDER_INFO_TABLE** and **APPROVE_TABLE**

The first one contains the information related to "orders".. **DO NOTE** that a single order may contain different "order lines" (thats why you'll see the order number repeated in the image below).Also, there exist a field called "PRICE" (this field is not SHOWN in my image) and CANCELLED (order line status)

The second table contains the information related to the "approvers" for the different order lines. Inside this table you will see a field called "APPROVERID", ITEMID (order line id) and "APPROVED" (order line status). The approvers must check if the price is okay or not. If the order line is okay, the approver will put a number 1 in the field "APPROVED". If the price is not correct, he will put a number 1 in the field CANCELLED in the other table.

Take a look at these images:

[image]

[image: image2]

**I have tried without success to obtain all the cancelled orders (an order is cancelled when all ITS order lines are cancelled) AND the approved order (an approved order may contain cancelled order lines) for an specific approver**

I tried so many times, using count operator, left join but i am completely lost :(

A guy suggested me to use this query:

```
SELECT web_order_id
FROM ORDER_INFO_TABLE oif
INNER JOIN APPROVE_TABLE apt
ON (oif.item_id = apt.item_id)
GROUP BY web_order_id
HAVING SUM(cancelled) = COUNT(*);
```

*The problem is that it is not woking properly (it shows this error message: operand data type is invalid for sum operator) AND using this query i will not be able to obtain the CANCELLED and APPROVED orders for a specific approver.*

EDIT:

```
SELECT web_order_id
FROM ORDER_INFO_TABLE oif
INNER JOIN APPROVE_TABLE apt
ON (oif.item_id = apt.item_id **and apt.APPROVERID = 'RANDOM@MAILNATOR.COM'**)
GROUP BY web_order_id
HAVING SUM(cancelled) = COUNT(*);
```

Comment: could please add your expected output

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Well, i should be able to obtain a column with all the web_order_id (order numbers). In the query i want to find for a specific approver (for example: random@mailnator.com) and obtain all the different web_order_ids that were cancelled and approved for this guy. Do you get me?

Comment: add it in table format - it will be easier to understand

Comment: Is `Cancelled` a numeric type, or string type? Might just need a cast.

Comment: @Ben Yeah,the problem is that now i am getting a single row which contains the web_order_ids BUT i dont know who was the approver

Comment: Well, that's a different question. That said, the way you explained it you can have multiple approvers per order right?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, different approvers can approve/reject different orders (i mean, the approver will approve the different *order lines*..if every single order line is rejected then the whole order was rejected). Do you get me?

Comment: @Ben Dude, there are many approvers and every approver will be given different orders to approve/reject THE LINES inside the order. The order itself have different "lines" (1,2 or more) and the approver will approve or reject those lines of an order. If the approver reject ALL the lines of an order, the order itself is considered CANCELLED, BUT if the order had 3 lines and he approved 1 and rejected 2 the order itself is considered APPROVED

Comment: @Ben So,i want to obtain all the order numbers (web_order_ids) whose lines were ALL rejected AND also those order whose lines were not cancelled at all

Comment: If you also want orders where no lines were cancelled, just add an `OR` clause to the `HAVING` clause in the answer below where the count of cancelled equals 0. 
On the other hand, if CANCELLED means all rows cancelled, and APPROVED means any row approved, then...well that's just all rows.
Is this a real system? This seems like a terrible design with really weird requirements.

Comment: @Ben yeah, kinda weird. Dude, isnt this condition only giving me all the CANCELLED rows: *HAVING SUM(CAST(oif.cancelled AS int)) = COUNT(*);*?
Also, i dont know how to filter by approverid because i want to know which order lines were approved/rejected by which approver

Comment: Could you please help me to modify the query? I am really confused :/

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: If you just want to select order from specific approver then just use simple select with join:

```
SELECT oif.web_order_id, oif.item_id, apt.approverid,
    oif.cancelled, apt.approved
FROM ORDER_INFO_TABLE oif
INNER JOIN APPROVE_TABLE apt
ON oif.item_id = apt.item_id
WHERE apt.approverid = 'RANDOM@MAILNATOR.COM'
ORDER BY oif.web_order_id, oif.item_id;
```

Seems that your `cancelled` column datatype is `VARCHAR`. You should convert it to number before using `SUM` function

```
SELECT oif.web_order_id
FROM ORDER_INFO_TABLE oif
INNER JOIN APPROVE_TABLE apt
ON oif.item_id = apt.item_id
GROUP BY oif.web_order_id
HAVING SUM(CAST(oif.cancelled AS int)) = COUNT(*);
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working but now i dont know who was the approver for each order.

Comment: Do you understand me?

Comment: @programming_always then you could edit your question for more information about your data and please show sample data with your expected output for that data. For e.g, how many approver could be for an order with many items, because as your query, two table join by `item_id` not order_id.

Comment: Dude, there are many approvers and every approver will be given different orders to approve/reject THE LINES inside the order. The order itself have different "lines" (1,2 or more) and the approver will approve or reject those lines of an order. If the approver reject ALL the lines of an order, the order itself is considered CANCELLED, BUT if the order had 3 lines and he approved 1 and rejected 2 the order itself is considered APPROVED

Comment: Do you get me now? So,i want to obtain all the order numbers (web_order_ids) whose lines were ALL rejected or at least 1 was approved

Comment: In this case, i think this condition is not enough: *HAVING SUM(CAST(oif.cancelled AS int)) = COUNT(*);* because i am only getting ALL the web_order_ids whose lines were ALL CANCELLED.

Comment: I want a query that show all the web_order_id (order numbers) whose lines were ALL cancelled AND orders whose lines werenot cancelled at all.

Comment: @programming_always Could you please edit your question with sample data and expected result?

Comment: Dude, take a look. I've edited the question. I've added this condition:and apt.APPROVERID = 'RANDOM@MAILNATOR.COM' so i will be able to find those order number for a specific approver. The problem is that i am only getting the order number (web_order_id) whose lines were all CANCELLED but i also need those order numbers that have at least 1 row approved.

Comment: @programming_always so what is sample data and your expected output? If you want orders with all cancelled along with orders with at least 1 approved, then just select * from table1 inner join table2 without group by and having